# CSS Browser appearance inconsistent

Tags: html, css

The way I want the CSS elements should appear works on firefox but not chrome and IE.

Link to the screenshot comparison is below

http://postimg.org/image/3sjfgyjzh/

essentially I have four inline li which are images, when viewed in chrome or IE the third of four falls onto a new line when there is clearly enough space to fit all the elements.

hopefully someone can help, Thanks :)

```
 #footer-nav {
     background: #999;
     /* for non-css3 browsers */
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0E63AD', endColorstr='#0E63AD');
     /* for IE */
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#5FAFF5), to(#0E63AD));
     /* for webkit browsers */
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #0E63AD, #5FAFF5);
     /* for firefox 3.6+ */
     padding-top: 0px;
     padding-bottom: 14px;
     margin: 0px !important;
     position: absolute !important;
     bottom: 20px !important;
     right: 0px !important;
     left: -9px !important;
 }
 .nav-menu li {
     display:inline;
     margin-left: 16px;
     /*padding-left: 8px;*/
     right: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: That's why you need a [CSS reset sheet](https://github.com/murtaugh/HTML5-Reset/blob/master/_/css/reset.css). Browsers default settings are custom and there's no universal value for any CSS attribute.

Comment: @JeffNoel Unless you can actually point to the part of the reset that's going to fix the problem, your recommendation is not helpful.

Comment: @cimmanon This was a general statement to let people realize that browsers default rules are totally different, therefor they might understand that it's not the only issue that might come out if they let the browser show elements the way it wants to.

Comment: @JeffNoel CSS resets are snake oil.  Do you know how often "use a reset" is recommended and it *actually* solves the problem?  Not very often.

Comment: What mode is the page rendered in? It is in quirks mode or standards mode? Press F12 in IE to find out. If it's in quirks mode, then you've found the problem.

Comment: @cimmanon Of course, specifying your own rules afterwards is needed; reset sheets won't solve the problem by themselves. But CSS reset sheets are highly encouraged when the developer or client wants the website to be seen exactly the same way in every browser. In this actual case, specifying a null font-size for the parent element could fix the problem and the reset sheet could ensure all browser see it the same way.